# Do we need both [emgu] and [emgucv]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm not sure why there are 2 tags for the same thing:

- [emgu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgu) with 355 questions tagged
- [emgucv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgucv) with 1075 questions tagged
- [180 questions have both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgu+emgucv)

The tag wikis are very similar. Do we need both tags?

As the name of the library is **Emgu CV**, I suggest that there should be only one tag: [emgucv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgucv)

Comment: The tag wiki for `emgu` says `An alternative tag is [emgucv]`. My vote for what it's worth would be to burninate `emgu` and offer it as a sacrifice unto the great and mighty roomba.

Comment: Bless the library writers that can pick a four letter word that still uniquely identifies their library.  Not that easy.  Curse the users of the library that think it is important to append a two letter acronym.  Yes, it needs to be a synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[emgu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgu) has been merged into [emgucv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgucv)

Comment: The [emgu] tag was recreated. There are still 77 questions remaining in the tag.

Comment: I went through all the 77 questions, and re-merged the tags. I add the tag as a synonym, and now this issue shouldn't reoccur.